# What is the year in which more people joined than in any other year? PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to find the year in which more people joined than in any other year in PSQL?

my table called(people) and has many columns in it, one of them is a column called(joinedYear) which is an integer.

Assuming that these are the joinedYears that the column has 2007, 2009, 2009, 2008.

What is the command that is going to give me the result of 2009.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT joinedYear, count(joinedYear) as numOfPeople
FROM people
GROUP by joinedYear
ORDER BY numOfPeople DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This will give you the `joinedYear` in which most number of people joined in.

However it is possible that two years may have same but highest value if this matters in your case than try increasing the number of records required with `LIMIT *;`

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for answering and explaining your answer